# The API to check the validity of user's subscription purchase in android returns "valid" even if the subscription is expired.

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing

We are offering subscriptions on our android app. The app sends the receipt or purchase token to our server and we store the expiry date of the subscription. When it reaches the expiry date we check if the subscription is still valid using this api.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/packageName/subscriptions/subscriptionId/purchases/token
```

Basically, it returns the following.

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "initiationTimestampMsec": long,
  "validUntilTimestampMsec": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean
}
```

By checking the value of "autoRenewing", we know that the subscription is still active. If it's active, we update the expiration date. However, starting June the api gives weird results on some of the subscription purchases.

The `autoRenewing` field is still returning true but the `validUntilTimestampMsec` was not updated. Until now, those subscriptions are still returning the same result. We checked the transactions in our google checkout account, the subscription are already cancelled, but the api is still showing it as active.

Are we missing something?

Comment: I also reported this issue on google play. No response yet.